# How to identify the slowest methods using Perfino?

Tags: install4j, jprofiler, perfino

I'm trying to improve my application. So I have installed `perfino` on my development server and it started to monitor my application. Now I would like to know the most slowest methods on my application. Where can I find that with `perfino`? I'm also trying to use `jprofiler` to find this information, but I'm kind of lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfino does not work on the method level like a Java profiler, it measures "business transactions" that you can set up in the recording settings. Those are either web request, EJB calls or selected methods, either annotated with special annotations or configured as POJO methods in the recording settings.

For slow transactions, you can then look at method samples and find associated hot spots on the method level.